# "By" parameter in list_emails() not working

Tags: r, microsoft365r

Is the "by" parameter in the `list_emails()` not working for anyone else?
I've tried both "received" and "received desc", and they return the same email:

```
library(Microsoft365R)
my_outlook <- get_business_outlook()
email <- my_outlook$list_emails(by = "received desc", filter = "startswith(sender/emailAddress/address,'example')", n = 1)
email <- my_outlook$list_emails(by = "received", filter = "startswith(sender/emailAddress/address,'example')", n = 1)
```